# Php syntax error t_variable error?

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to post to the users wall i have there id and offline token stored in the database

```
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT token FROM usersoffline", $link2);
$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result22);
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usersoffline") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>id</th> <th>Toekn</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['uid'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['token'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 


$target = $row['uid'] ;
    $attachment =  array(
             'access_token' => $row['token'],
              'message' => 'Did a Test Post :',
                    'name' => "Offline posting using stored tokens",
                    'link' => "url",
                    'description' => "This post was made using a stored access token",
              'picture'=>"",
            );
    $ret_code=$facebook->api('/'.$target.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);



} 
echo "</table>";
```

for some resson it is not posting ???

Comment: what is the value of $ret_code? I believe access token should be attached to the URL, not posted in $attachment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$target = $row['uid']` needs a semicolon after it.

Comment: Same error? Can we see some more of the script BEFORE the line the error is talking about?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse, or some other IDE? It will have syntax highlighting, and let you see when you have parse errors. Also, that's the only bit wrong with this chunk of code, so your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Well the script is not posting to any ones wall and all the tokens and ids are stored probley  have tested them ... can you see any problems or any way that the script wouldn't post to the users page ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are including and initializing the Facebook library properly: `$facebook = new Facebook(...);`
2. Make sure your app has granted the `publish_stream` permission
3. wrap your Facebook calls in a `try/catch` clause to *catch* errors - [reference](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php#L36)
4. You don't need the `offline_access` permission
5. Based on #4, you don't need to append the `access_token` in your `$attachment` var